# Algorithm for max flow and min cut, simultaneous

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, computer-science, education, network-flow

Good morning everyone. I failed a graph theory exam last week and I would like to know how to solve some of the problems I got because I don't have any idea. One of the problems was asking for an algorithm. The problem is:

> Let $R = (G,S,T,c)$ be a network, $x$ is a flow in $R$ and $(S,T)$ a cut in $R$. Write an algorithm of complexity $\mathcal O(n+m)$ which will decide if $x$ is a maximum flow and $(S,T)$ a min cut, simultaneous.

Here I tried to use Ford Fulkerson with a queue, but I think my problem was on the queue. I didn't know how to include the min cut in the Ford Fulkerson Algorithm.

What is the right algorithm for this?

Comment: Are you really supposed to construct the flow, which Ford-Fulkerson does? Or only decide if a given flow in a given network (with a given cut) is maximal? You know that a flow (or rather, its value) is maximal if and only if the capacity of the corresponding cut is minimal. You already know the cut. The $O(n+m)$ suggests iterating through the adjacency list of $G$ and using $x$ in some way. I assume that $n$ is the number of vertices, and $m$ is the number of edges, of $G$.

Comment: It's not a must to construct the flow, I mean it is not asked for.  And yes, n is the number of vertices, m the number of edges.  I think that the problem asks for an algorithm to decide if a given flow is maximal etc. It's pretty bad formulated, I know.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the set of vertices $A$ $=\{u$: net flow out of $u$ is positive $\}$, and for each vertex $u \in A$ let $y(u)$ be the net flow out of $u$. To calculate the net flow of a vertex $u$, calculate the flow out of $u$ given by $\sum x(u,v); v \in N_G(u)$, and subtract from that the flow into $u$ given by $\sum x(v,u); v \in N_G(u)$.
2. Then $(S,T)$ is a minimum cut iff $\sum_{u \in A} y(u) = \sum_{e \in (S,t)} c(e)$,
   where $c(e)$ denotes the capacity of $e$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped me. I wish you a nice weekend!